# Hasp dongle only temporarily recognized

Tags: windows-xp, dongle, parallel-port

On a Windows XP system, I have to use a proprietary software to pilot a wood cutting machine.

The software is protected by a hasp dongle, plugged into a parallel port. It was previously set up on a ~20yo Compaq computer under Windows 98 and working fine.

However, on this specific computer, the software seems to recognize the dongle at first, but after a random amount of time loses tracks of it. It's an old 16bit program and needs to be restarted to detect the dongle again. So basically it always gets stuck before I can send any work to the cutting machine.

The developing company is a small local one and there is very little documentation that I can rely on. I tried contacting their support but to no avail.

I have tried every available mode for the parallel port in the bios ("normal, bi-lateral, EPP and ECP"), but it didn't make any difference.

So there is something messing with the communication between the cutting software and the parallel port, but I have no idea what to do in order to find out what.

Motherboard model is MS-6712 :

[image]

Dongle looks like this :

[image]

Comment: It's possible that there's physical damage to one of the ports, the cable, or the cable plugs.  It may be worth your while to get a USB->parallel adapter , get a newer PC, install Win98 into a VM and ensure that it gets exclusive input from that USB->parallel adapter, and see if you can make it work that way.

Comment: it may be a pass-through dongle and realtime lpt communication may take some hoop-jumping to get working correctly via USB. One thing to try is: reduce the "transmission retry" setting for the port in the Windows Device properties.

Comment: ChristopherHostage I considered this option, but as you said this would require a new PC, and as Yorick pointed out, without guarantee that it could work. But I keep it opened as last resort.

Comment: @Yorik How can I do that in Windows XP ? I can't find this option in device settings.

Comment: Oh wait "transmission retry" seems to be a parameter associated with a printer, but the dongle doesn't appear as printer device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by installing Windows 98 instead of XP.

I don't really understand why, but the problem seemed to be an incompatibility with the software and the OS. The parallel port was fine, the bios settings didn't matter since the communication mode needed was the simplest (unidirectional mode I think ?).